# Panic running async code while dropping Rust Future

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, rusoto

I have an app using `#[tokio::main]`, that creates several resources on AWS in one of its tasks. I've implemented cleaning up those resources in `Drop` handlers. However those cleanup functions are async, so I am using `block_on` to ensure they run synchronously before returning from `drop`.

```
use futures::executor::block_on;

struct EventQueue(pub String);

impl Drop for EventQueue {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        block_on(delete_queue(&self.0))
    }
}

pub async fn delete_queue(queue_url: &str) {
    let sqs = rusoto_sqs::SqsClient::new(REGION);
    sqs.delete_queue(DeleteQueueRequest {
        queue_url: queue_url.to_string(),
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}
```

The `main` function doesn't return until a `signal::ctrl_c().await.unwrap();` completes, after which I think the Tokio runtime is dropped, and the spawned tasks are cancelled. I believe the interaction with `block_on` is failing because the runtime is no longer usable.

Here's the [panic output](https://gist.github.com/anacrolix/8aebc5e87f245dc77aa999930418f28c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using [`tokio::select!`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/tokio/macro.select.html) in tokio 0.2.11. prevented the panics, and had the desired behaviour. I think because `select!` cancels the other futures before the runtime goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing async destructor is very tricky and some work have been done [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/asynchronous-destructors/11127), but not running `drop` is not considered as a bug, ["Exiting without calling destructors"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-not-considered-unsafe.html#exiting-without-calling-destructors).